# load a float+ string table

Tags: python, numpy

I have a table which contains both floats and strings. When I'm trying to load it by `np.loadtxt(file.txt)`, I got an error like

```
could not convert string to float: \Omega_b
```

How can I fix it.

Comment: what output are you expecting ?

Comment: Can you include a sample of your `file.txt` and the line where the `mega_b` appears?

Comment: I need to use the data and the labels in the file, to produce a new table after doing some math.

Comment: 1  0.2238592E-01  0.2112570E-01  0.2379103E-01  0.2073186E-01  0.2425390E-01   \Omega_b h^2

Answer (score 3):

You can load using the `dtype` option to create a [structured array](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.rec.html):

```
np.loadtxt(fname, dtype=[('col1_name', '|S10'), ('col2_name', float)])
```

Or if you don't want to specify which dtypes it should use you can go for what was suggested by @atomh33ls: `dtype=None`.

[See additional options for `np.loadtxt`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.loadtxt.html) so that you can tune it to your needs.